# What happens with allocatable components of derived types when i use automatic reallocation?

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

In my program, I want to create a container type, containing an array of a certain derived type. I want to add type bound procedures for the container, that invoke procedures on all components of the array. Since the size of the array varies, I tried to use the automatic reallocation feature. I ran into troubles with allocatable characters.

Here is a small snippet, showing the setup:

```
module realloc_test                                                                                                                                                                                                
  implicit none                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  type :: number_t                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    character(:), allocatable :: number_c    ! this does not work                                                                                                                                                                              
!    character(len=10)         :: number_c   ! this works
    integer                   :: number_i                                                                                                                                                                                            
  end type number_t                                                                                                                                                                                                

  type number_container                                                                                                                                                                                            
    integer :: listsize                                                                                                                                                                                            
    type(number_t), allocatable, dimension(:) :: all_numbers                                                                                                                                                       
  contains                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    procedure add                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  end type number_container                                                                                                                                                                                        

contains                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  subroutine add (this, number_in)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    class(number_container), intent(inout) :: this                                                                                                                                                                 
    type(number_t), intent(inout) :: number_in                                                                                                                                                                     

    if (.not. allocated(this%all_numbers)) then                                                                                                                                                                    
      allocate(this%all_numbers(1), source = number_in)                                                                                                                                                            
      this%listsize = 1                                                                                                                                                                                            
    else  
      ! reallocate -> add entry                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      this%all_numbers = [ this%all_numbers, number_in ]                                                                                                                                                           
      this%listsize = SIZE (this%all_numbers)                                                                                                                                                                      
    end if                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  end subroutine add                                                                                                                                                                                               

end module realloc_test                                                                                                                                                                                            

program testprog                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  use realloc_test                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  implicit none                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  integer :: i                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  type(number_t) :: one, two, three, four                                                                                                                                                                          
  type(number_container) :: number_list                                                                                                                                                                            

  one = number_t ('one', 1)                                                                                                                                                                                        
  two = number_t ('two', 2)                                                                                                                                                                                        
  three = number_t ('three', 3)                                                                                                                                                                                    
  four = number_t ('four', 4)                                                                                                                                                                                      

  call number_list%add(one)                                                                                                                                                                                        
  call number_list%add(two)                                                                                                                                                                                        
  call number_list%add(three)                                                                                                                                                                                      
  call number_list%add(four)                                                                                                                                                                                       

  do i = 1, number_list%listsize                                                                                                                                                                                   
    print*, number_list%all_numbers(i)%number_c                                                                                                                                                                    
    print*, number_list%all_numbers(i)%number_i                                                                                                                                                                    
  end do                                                                                                                                                                                                           
end program testprog
```

I compiled with ifort, using

```
-assume realloc_lhs
```

to enable automatic reallocation. The output reads:

```
           1
 ??n
           2

           3
 four
           4
```

The last entry is displayed correctly. Copying the old part of the array seems to cause problems with the allocatable component. When I use a fixed character length, I don't run into trouble. What exactly happens, when automatic reallocation is used that way? Are there other options to do this more safely?

Comment: An unfortunate bug I ran into myself some time ago. I hoped they would fix it when they claim full Fortran 2003 support in the new version, but they didn't yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are seeing the consequences of the compiler bug described at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/incorrect-results-assigning-array-constructor-with-allocatable-components .  This bug is still in ifort 15.0.0.

The workaround shown in that link is to use a temporary to build the array ahead of the final assignment to the allocatable component.